# Django-CMS nav third child?

Tags: html, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I need to display the third level in my navigation. Only the second level is displayed.

Like this:

```
|- Home
|- About us
|-|- History
|-|-|- WW1
|-|-|- WW2
|- Contact
```

I still hope there is someone who solved this problem! Thank youuu!

````
{% for child in children %}
    {% if child.is_leaf_node %}
        <li><a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ child.get_menu_title }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not child.is_leaf_node or child.ancestor %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ child.get_menu_title }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }} ></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu xpl1">
            {% for kid in child.get_descendants %}
                {% if kid.is_leaf_node %}
                    <li><a href="{{ kid.attr.redirect_url|default:kid.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ kid.get_menu_title }}">{{ kid.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if not kid.is_leaf_node or kid.ancestor %}
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ kid.attr.redirect_url|default:kid.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ kid.get_menu_title }}">{{ kid.get_menu_title }} ></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu xpl1">
                            {% for kidkid in kid.get_descendants %}
                                <li><a href="{{ kidkid.attr.redirect_url|default:kidkid.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ kidkid.get_menu_title }}">{{ kidkid.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} ```
````

Comment: Why not keep things simple like the default template & recursively render each level? https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templates/menu/menu.html

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I needed to solve the same problem. I combined some of the original code and some from the [Github repo](https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templates/menu/menu.html) mentioned in the comments.

Here is my solution:

```
{% load menu_tags %}


{% for child in children %}
    {% if child.is_leaf_node %}
        <li><a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ child.get_menu_title }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not child.is_leaf_node or child.ancestor %}
    <li class="dropdown child{% if child.selected %} selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %} ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %} sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %} descendant{% endif %}">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```